# Desura pre-installed game activation wrong harrdive?

Tags: desura

I've been attempting to activate pre-installed games on Desura, which is possible in the application - there is a problem, though.

Apparently it doesn't register the games you have installed on your other Harddrives.

For example; Games on my D: drive aren't being detected, only games installed on my C: drive are detected by Desura.

The problem with this, is that if I wanted to download mods for my pre-installed Amnesia, I can't as Desura doesn't register that I already own and have already paid for Amnesia.

Anyone know of this issue?

Comment: This kind of reads like a bug report, which I would send to Desura rather than post here.

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't see why this isn't acceptable here if similar questions about Steam are.  If anyone knows a workaround, that's what he wants to know.